# How to hide and unhide the html textfield as per dropbox selection- HTML,Python

Tags: jquery, python, html

I have a python file validity.py. In that file I have the following functions:-

```
def login():
    return '''
    <body bgcolor="#FFDEAD">
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <img src='http://%s:%s/login/guavusLogo.png'>
        <h1>Validity</h1><br>
        <h2> Configuration Parameters</h2><br>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <tr><td><lable>Chose from the following</td><td> <select name="options">
            <option value="unhide">unhide</option>
            <option value="hide">hide</option>
        </select></td><tr>
        <td>Start Date: </td><td><input name="startDate" type="text" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>End Date:</td><td> <input name="endDate" type="text" /></td></tr>
        </table>
        <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
    $("select").change(function() {
    if ($("select option:selected")[0].value == 'unhide') {
            $("[name='startDate']").show();
            $("[name='endDate']").show();
    }
    else {
            $("[name='startDate']").hide();
            $("[name='endDate']").hide();
         }
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="%s:%s/login/validate.min.js"></script>
    </body>
''' %(host,port,host,port)

def yes():
...
...
do something
...
...

def no():
...
...
do something  
...
...

def do_login():
    startDate = request.forms.get('startDate')
    endDate = request.forms.get('endDate')
    callOptions = request.forms.get('options')
    paramList = [startDate, endDate, callOptions]
    if '' in paramList or None in paramList:
             return "<p>Insufficient Arguments Entered. Please enter all the arguments mentioned in the config page</p>"
    else:
            if callOptions == "yes":
                    yes()
            elif callOptions == "no":
                    no()

run(host=host, port=port, debug=True)

do_login()
```

Don't worry about how I am bringing the web page on the server, because all that have been taken care of already. I want that when I load the page on the server, I want the the text fields startTime and endTime to be hidden if 'no' is selected from the drop box and unhide them if 'yes' is selected.

So in the do_login() function, where I have put if conditions that if callOptions == "no", then it calls the specified function, but I want the text fields to hide and the other way round.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery (which you already seem to be using) you can do this on the client without requiring any server side processing.

This should work without changes to your HTML:

```
<script>
$("select").change(function() {
    if ($("select option:selected")[0].value == 'hide') {
        $("[name='startDate']").hide();
        $("[name='endDate']").hide();
    } else {
        $("[name='startDate']").show();
        $("[name='endDate']").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Also, it should be `<label>`, not `<lable>`, and you should close that tag.

Comment: I have edited. But still not working? Is it correct?

Comment: I think it cant fetch the jquery min.js file.

Comment: You need to close the script tag, i.e. `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`. Also you need to add an opening script tag before the line `$("select").change(function()`

Comment: Thanks:)It worked. Also they just go invisible, is there any way I could disable them. I mean make them non functional as well?

Comment: The jquery documentation is pretty good :) See http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/